# Javascript/Jquery: Using + sign on a string.

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I'm creating a filter using select elements. This is for a wheel store, so the values would be bolt patterns, sizes, colors, etc.

I have to make an AJAX call with all the selected values in the format:

```
value1+value2+value3....
```

The only way I could think of to do this would be to iterate over the selected options and add to the sign + and the selected value to the string and in the end use substring to remove the first + sign.

```
var SelectedFilters = '';
$('#CategoryFilter .BlockContent select').each(function(index, element) {
    value = $(element).find('option:selected').val();
    if(value != "Choose One"){
        SelectedFilters += ('+' + value);  // This is the line with the problem
    });
 SelectedFilters = SelectedFilters.substring(1,SelectedFilters.length);
```

The problem I'm having is with line 5 above. I'm getting a Syntax, unexpected token error, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that line, but there's something wrong with the next line:

```
    });
```

If that's supposed to be the end of the `.each()` callback, then you're missing the `}` for the `if` statement. If it's not supposed to be the end of the function, then the `);` is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, that was it. Thank you Pointy. I will accept as answer as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors, use JSLint or JSHint to fix them.

Also, you can greatly simplify this process:

```
var SelectedFilters = $('#CategoryFilter .BlockContent option:selected')
    .filter(function ()  { return this.value !== 'Choose One'; })
    .map(function () { return this.value; }).get().join('+');
```